# How to lock the screen on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-ui, touch

As the alert("~"); is called, the user has to touch the screen first, and then he can do more operations on the screen.
   But I use jQueryUI to create my customized jQueryUI dialog, and it won't lock the screen...  What can I do to implement this function. 
   UPDATE: 

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#story_pages").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600          

    });
});
</script>
```

Some event trigger:

```
$( '#story_pages').dialog("open");
```

I still click other button on the application.

Comment: Can you provide some example code that you're having a problem with? I just tested a jQueryUI modal dialog in Safari on my iPad and it worked perfectly. Seeing as Phonegap is just deploying your HTML/JS/CSS through a webview, I see no reason why this should be different.

Comment: Maybe I should change the terminology: "Lock". Here, I mean as the 
jQueryUI window pops out, the user can't touch any other buttons, items on the html. But "lock" seems to mean the screen won't rotate.
What key word should I make?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% clear but from your comments and description I think by 'lock' you mean when the dialog is presented you do not want the user to be able to interact with anything else on the page (until the dialog is dismissed). This is called a 'modal dialog'.

In your parameters array you need to set `modal` to `true`:

```
$("#story_pages").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 600,        
    modal: true
});
```

See [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) for an example of what this does and what the code should look like.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what I want! Do we have more accurate description to this issue? Maybe some terminology or ...

Comment: Modal is the correct terminology, 'modal dialog' and 'modal window' are both correct terms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window